# Why browser is returning empty string on style.height ? How to get actual height of an element?

Tags: javascript, css, height

Simple one line of html:

`<div onclick="alert(this.style.height)">sometext</div>`

and alert gives:

[image]

but it should be like `10px` or sth like that.

Comment: Did you try setting the style explicitly? `<div style="height:10px;" onclick="alert(this.style.height)">sometext</div>`

Comment: use jquery! you'll have a much more simpler time, it has the $.height() function to tell the height. Also you might find that there is no height so you have to check lineHeight and padding (top and bottom).

Comment: opera version 11, but this is irrelevant, even browser is irrelevant, I first thought that this is only opera quirk. I will change the question a little.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you use this.style.height, the height must have been specified on the element first, like this:

```
<div style="height: 15px;" onclick="alert(this.style.height)">sometext</div>
```

Otherwise, you should probably use offsetHeight or clientHeight:

```
<div onclick="alert(this.offsetHeight)">sometext</div>
```

Comment: +1 it works. But how? what is the difference between `height` and `offsetHeight`?

Comment: The `height` is only available if you have explicitly set the height. But `offsetHeight` will always be the calculated height. If you are unsure on when to use either then one simple tip is to use `offsetHeight` when you are checking what height it has and `height` when you are setting a new height.

Comment: wat about `clientHeight`? is that the same as `offsetHeight`?

Comment: See question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106538/difference-between-offsetheight-and-clientheight

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that you don't actually have any style rules setting the element's height.  To get the actual rendered height of an element, use [`element.clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientHeight).

Answer (score 2):

`object.style.whatever` only returns values that have been set using the style attribute in markup, or the style property in script, thus:

```
<div style="height:10px" onclick="alert(this.style.height)">sometext</div>
```

or

```
theDiv.style.height = "10px";
```

The method [getComputedStyle](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle) allows you to access the style properties, as they are defined by the cascade (i.e. using `@style` as above, or `<stylesheet>...</stylesheet>` or whatever mechanism)

EDIT:
It may benefit you to use an established cross-browser JS library, rather than access this property directly, and have to deal with the quirks of diverse browsers.  Older versions of IE (for example) do not support this method.

Answer (score 1):

Use clientHeight or offsetHeight property. Check this url

http://help.dottoro.com/ljuxqbfx.php