# javascript css style.width keeps returning incorrect

Tags: javascript

I am working on a simple javascript function but it won't work.
It includes an if statement that checks if the `style.width === "50px"`, but it keeps returning `false`

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <button id="menuknop" onclick="menu()"></button>    
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Projecten</li>
            <li>Over ons</li>
            <li>Contactt</li>
         </ul>

    </div>

    <div class=content>
        <ul class="ulmenu">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Projecten</li>
            <li>Over ons</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function menu(){
    var header = document.querySelector(".header");
    if(header.style.height === "50px") {
        console.log("doet het")
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why browser is returning empty string on style.height ? How to get actual height of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646229/why-browser-is-returning-empty-string-on-style-height-how-to-get-actual-height)

Comment: does it have css height: 50px?

Comment: @ChrisLi .header {
 height:50px;
 background-color:#CCCCCC;
 display:flex;}

Comment: is you selector selecting the right element?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
window.getComputedStyle(header).getPropertyValue('height')
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

You can also use `header.offsetHeight` or `header.clientHeight`