# How to measure height of a div that has no height

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to get the height of a div. I can't set the height in css because the content may change (it depends on what's in it).
I tried:

```
var buttonsHeight = $(".buttonsContainer").height();
```

and

```
var buttonsHeight = $(".buttonsContainer").outerHeight();
```

and

```
var buttonsHeight = $(".buttonsContainer").innerHeight();
```

In every case `buttonsHeight` is `null`.

CSS:

```
.buttonsContainer{
  padding:31px 16px 0;
  position:fixed;
}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/U7Kck/3/

If you replace 
padding:20px 0; with a height:40px then buttonsContainer looks fine...

Comment: It's impossible to identify the source of the problem with the information you've given. Could you possibly re-create it with [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: You're sure the jQuery is selecting an existing element? Try and `console.log($(".buttonsContainer").length);`

Comment: If `buttonsHeight` is `null` then the element doesn't exist at the time you're running your query

Comment: Did you inspect the element to make sure it actually has a computed height ?

Comment: create fiddle for your problem?????

Comment: Show your HTML code to let us help you.

Comment: Fiddle created:
http://jsfiddle.net/U7Kck/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttonsHeight = $(".buttonsContainer")[0].clientHeight
```

Comment: @Mag Are you sure the `$('.buttonsContainer')` match with some elements?

Comment: Yep :)   
Fiddle created: jsfiddle.net/U7Kck/3

Answer (score 0):

I think when the page opens it is given height to the div, I can't test now, but I guess you can get it with:

```
$(".buttonsContainer").css("height")
```

Comment: It will return height as string with unit included like "123px".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var elem = $('.buttonsContainer')[0];
buttonsHeight = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue('height');
```

documentation for `getComputedStyle` is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle)

Answer (score 0):

These jQuery methods works fine. 
Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var buttonsHeight = $(".buttonsContainer").height();
   console.log("height: " + buttonsHeight);
    buttonsHeight = $(".buttonsContainer").innerHeight();
   console.log("inner height: " + buttonsHeight);
    buttonsHeight = $(".buttonsContainer").outerHeight();
   console.log("outer height: " + buttonsHeight);
});
```

with simple HTML like:

```
<div class="buttonsContainer">Some <br/>content</div>
<div class="buttonsContainer">Some content</div>
```

Even with multiple `buttonsContainer` elements it works fine. Just returns height of first element found.

http://jsfiddle.net/KBR3r/2/

So I guess that the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

`clientHeight` and `offsetHeight` does the job for you. Check them here they are working. Use any of the above based on your requirement that whether you consider border also into the width. http://jsfiddle.net/KzTDS/. To get more idea of `offsetHeight` and `clientHeight` check this [difference between offsetHeight and clientHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106538/difference-between-offsetheight-and-clientheight)

And here is how to use

```
 document.getElementById('button').clientHeight; // Same as below but does not include border scrollbar and no margin
 document.getElementById('button').offsetHeight; // content, padding, border, scrollbar and no margin
```