# Why scrollHeight is bigger than offsetHeight, when used inline-block and DOCTYPE html?

Tags: css, html

We migrated our HTML application from DOCTYPE XTHML 1.0 to DOCTYPE HTML.
And we saw that in some DIV appeared a vertical scroll.

These DIV has layout similar to that:
**CSS**

```
#scrollContainer,
#overflowedNode 
{
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}

#overflowedNode 
{
    display: inline-block
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="scrollContainer">
    <div id="overflowedNode"></div>
</div>
```

In this case, the DIV with id "scrollContainer" has a calculated height:

```
offsetHeight = 100;
scrollHeight = 105;
```

I think, that a vertical scroll appears, because the difference in height is 5 pixels.
But if you add at least one letter to content in the DIV with id "overflowedNode", then scrollHeight will be equal to the offsetHeight.

### Why is there a difference between offsetHeight and scrollHeight to 5px and how to fix it?

*Example to reproducing:* https://jsfiddle.net/yaznayka/204qntjh/5/

Comment: You can read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19719861/2686143

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but the scrollbar is only gone in XHTML 1.0 Transitional. In Strict you also got the scrollbar.

Comment: @guvenckardas, i know a difference between offsetHeight and scrollHeight. But in this case not used paddings, borders, or somewhat else.

Answer (score 2):

i was wondering the same thing...so i did a little test...i made sure nothing had margins...well the li's did..so i took it off and finally the scrollHeight, offsetHeight and clientHeight were the same....then I added the 10 px margin back...and it was 10 px off (which is confusing because I had like 20 li's...so I'd assume it would be 10*n in addition to the offset height...but it wasn't...its like it only counted the first one....really weird.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `display: inline-block` a space char appears. So, if you change it to `block` you get what you want.

```
#scrolled
{
    display: block; /* it's OK with block */
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I know that display: block is fix this problem. But i want to understand _why it is happening_.
And maybe there are situations when you need use style with display=inline-block.

Comment: This example shows that it's a space after the inline-block element https://jsfiddle.net/infous/204qntjh/7/ but I don't know why it disappears when you set text...

Comment: Only logical conclusion seems to be that you're preventing a line break with that somehow.