# HTML5, CSS3: Fixed size box with fluid to panel and rest-size bottom panel

Tags: html, css

I've spent ages scouring Google for an answer to my (relatively) simple problem, but haven't been able to find one.

I want to have a box (div?) in our web based business application that has a height of 100% of its parent container. Within that box, there should be 2 boxes, stacked on top of each other.

- The top box should resize according to its contents. (which will never be more than 50% of the total height).
- The bottom box should get the rest of the height. Any overflow should scroll.

Preferably no javascript should be used, especially no javascript timers that poll the heights every x milliseconds.

Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SEE THE THIRD EDIT, IT IS THE BEST SOLUTION**

---

I believe something similar to this is as close as you can get (assuming they are structured as I believe they are)

```
/* HTML */
<div id='container'>
    <div id='top'></div>
    <div id='bottom'></div>
</div>

/* CSS */
#container {
    width:300px; /* I assume the width/height is fixed */
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:4px; /* To remove the horiz scrollbar with width:100% and a border */
    overflow:hidden; /* Hide the content at the bottom to allow scroll */
}
#top {
    width:100%;
    max-height:50%; /* Using max-height allows it to size to smaller content */
    overflow:auto; /* Allow a scrollbar if necessary */
}
#bottom {
    height:100%; /* Take up the remaining space */
    overflow:auto; /* Allow a scrollbar if necessary */
}
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ErgtU/)

On a side note, your question should include the problem, your code related to the problem, and also your attempts at a solution. That way we can understand exactly what your problem is, see that you've tried a solution yourself, and use your actual code to fix it

---

**Edit**

In order to get it exactly as you desire, you could use a little javascript

```
var parent = document.getElementById('container'),
    top = parent.children[0],
    bottom = parent.children[1];

bottom.style.height =  parent.offsetHeight - top.offsetHeight - 8 + "px";
// The 8 comes from the vertical padding of the parent + 4 (not sure what the 4 
// is from, probably the four vertical padding widths). The actual number could
// be calculated dynamically, but that would require using getComputedStyle and
// is more work than it's worth since borders/padding don't change dynamically
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ErgtU/2/)

If you don't care about formatting then you could do it in one long line by

```
document.getElementById('bottom').style.height = document.getElementById('container').offsetHeight - document.getElementById('top').offsetHeight - 8 + "px";
```

Javascript is needed because you cannot set a height based on another element's variable height in pure CSS like you hope to. For more info on `offsetHeight`, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106538/difference-between-offsetheight-and-clientheight)

---

**Second Edit**

If you have to make it respond to input (I used `contenteditable`) you can use the `onclick` and `onkeyup` events to bind the function to it. You should have all the tools you need to make it the way you want it now, it is impossible for me to know exactly what you want or how you want it to behave

```
top.onkeyup = function() {
    bottom.style.height =  parent.offsetHeight - top.offsetHeight - 8 + "px";
}
top.onkeyup();
top.onclick = function() {
    top.onkeyup();
}
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/ErgtU/4/)

---

**Third Edit**

Not sure why I didn't think about this before, but this is a perfect situation for flexbox. It's simpler, more intuitive, and easier to manipulate. P.S. I included browser prefixes in the demo

```
#container {
    ...
    overflow:hidden; /* Hide overflow */
    /* I excluded vendor prefixes for the sake of brevity, they're in the demo */
    flex-flow: column; /* Makes content flow down instead of across */    
    display: flex;
}
#top {
    ...
    max-height:50%; /* Sets the max height... */
    overflow:auto; /* Make sure scrollbar is there */        
    box-flex: none;
    flex: none; /* In essence, this acts like `height:auto` */
}
#bottom {
    ...
    border:1px solid red;
    overflow:auto; /* Make sure scrollbar is there */        
    flex: 2; /* Can be any positive number in this case */
}
```

[**Awesome CSS only demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ErgtU/7/). For more information on flexbox, check out [this article](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), [this video series and post](http://www.sketchingwithcss.com/samplechapter/cheatsheet.html), and also [some examples](http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/jLecs). However, the best way to learn it is to try projects yourself in my view

Comment: Your answer is close. However, the bottom pane moves out of view. You cannot see the bottom. You're right about the code. I should have included one of my attempts. I have however tested 4+ different setups (with numerous small differences per setup) to try to get it to work, including "display: table". I have not come close to a solution yet, so I didn't think to include the (faulty) code.

Comment: To do any better you would need a line of javascript. Want me to add that solution?

Comment: If you could, yes, please.

Comment: @ErikvO. Updated my solution with a js fix (:

Comment: This is closer, however it's still not what I need. This just updates the heights once. I want the heights to be updated automatically when the contents of the top div changes. As it's meant as sort of a framework thing, it should do this automatically, instead of kicking the code off on click handlers etc.

Comment: Do you mean make it work while `top` is an input? What do you mean?

Comment: This control is part of a master page / template. The top part will be a filter for the details that will be displayed in the bottom part. Each page has a different amount (and different size) of filter controls. Some of the controls can expand/collapse. That's why the panel should resize automatically on change of its contents.

Comment: @ErikvO. Updated again to respond to input

Comment: I'd have to add a page load event to handle the first resize. However: I'm still not very happy with the javascript. Some of our controls might call event.stopPropagation. Therefore I'd hoped I could avoid javascript and create a HTML/CSS only solution. I guess this is the closest we can get. Unless someone else has another brilliant idea.

Comment: @ErikvO. Added a CSS-only flexbox solution, check it out!

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately it doesn't work in Firefox. It works great in IE and Chrome though. I'd have to dive into the details of the flexbox and see if it is a code issue, or a Firefox bug. For now this is the best thing I've seen yet!

Comment: @ErikvO. Unfortunately Firefox does not yet support `flex-flow` yet

Comment: I'll definately will keep an eye on firefox's progress, but for now I can't use this. I also still need to support IE8 :( It's a shame really, as this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: That's quite understandable, but there is no other work around besides the javascript solution (or a very similar js solution) I posted then