# Particles.js canvas does not work when positioned in other Bootstrap carousel slide position

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, canvas, carousel, particles.js

I'm making a website with the Bootstrap carousel wich should contains some animated canvas.
I'd like to use Particles.js animation on second slide but It does not work.
It works only on first slide and I can't figure out why.

Can someone help me?

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    #myCarousel {
      height: 500px
    }
    .carousel-inner > .item > img,
    .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
    }
    canvas {
      position: relative;
      /*pointer-events:none;*/
      top: 0;
      left: 0
    }
    /* Particles Canvas*/
    #particles-js{
      height: 500px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #D0EDF5;
      background-image: url('');
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <br>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <h1>First Slide</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <div id="particles-js"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <h1>Third Slide</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    particlesJS('particles-js',

      {
        "particles": {
          "number": {
            "value": 60,
            "density": {
              "enable": true,
              "value_area": 800
            }
          },
          "color": {
            "value": "#0A8B80"
          },
          "shape": {
            "type": "circle",
            "stroke": {
              "width": 0,
              "color": "#000000"
            },
            "polygon": {
              "nb_sides": 5
            },
            "image": {
              "src": "img/github.svg",
              "width": 100,
              "height": 50
            }
          },
          "opacity": {
            "value": 0.5,
            "random": false,
            "anim": {
              "enable": false,
              "speed": 1,
              "opacity_min": 0.1,
              "sync": false
            }
          },
          "size": {
            "value": 20,
            "random": true,
            "anim": {
              "enable": false,
              "speed": 40,
              "size_min": 0.1,
              "sync": false
            }
          },
          "line_linked": {
            "enable": true,
            "distance": 150,
            "color": "#65BBC4",
            "opacity": 0.4,
            "width": 2
          },
          "move": {
            "enable": true,
            "speed": 6,
            "direction": "none",
            "random": false,
            "straight": false,
            "out_mode": "out",
            "attract": {
              "enable": false,
              "rotateX": 600,
              "rotateY": 1200
            }
          }
        },
        "interactivity": {
          "detect_on": "canvas",
          "events": {
            "onhover": {
              "enable": true,
              "mode": "repulse"
            },
            "onclick": {
              "enable": true,
              "mode": "push"
            },
            "resize": true
          },
          "modes": {
            "grab": {
              "distance": 400,
              "line_linked": {
                "opacity": 1
              }
            },
            "bubble": {
              "distance": 400,
              "size": 80,
              "duration": 2,
              "opacity": 8,
              "speed": 3
            },
            "repulse": {
              "distance": 200
            },
            "push": {
              "particles_nb": 4
            },
            "remove": {
              "particles_nb": 2
            }
          }
        },
        "retina_detect": true,
        "config_demo": {
          "hide_card": false,
          "background_color": "#D0EDF5",
          "background_image": "",
          "background_position": "50% 50%",
          "background_repeat": "no-repeat",
          "background_size": "cover"
        }
      }
    );
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Moreover, I noticed that the animation starts while open the developer console of the browser like the examples below:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU4xn.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVFK5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when particles.js initializes, it reads the `offsetHeight` and `offsetWidth` properties[1], where these describe the size of visible area[2]. This might be a bug of particles.js, but you can catch the slide event of Bootstrap carousel then initialize the particles.js.

---

Additional notes:

Initializing particles.js after the slide event makes sure that when it happens, the target element is already visible, so that particles.js can get valid metrics.

Another solution is to fire a resize event after every slide event. The width and height will be recalculated[3]. This is also why the author of this question can start the animation by opening the developer console.

Ref:

- [1]: https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/blob/d01286d6dcd61f497d07cc62bd48e692f6508ad5/particles.js#L18
- [2]: [difference between offsetHeight and clientHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106538/difference-between-offsetheight-and-clientheight)
- [3]: https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/blob/d01286d6dcd61f497d07cc62bd48e692f6508ad5/particles.js#L101

Comment: Thank to your suggestion I found the solution.
I just changed the element where it gets its properties from canvas_el to the element where the canvas is contained (the carousel) and now works.
It even solve the second problem just doing the same thing on resize listener and retina init.

Comment: Explain more clearly! The answer is not very explanatory!

Comment: @Sibidharan Which part do you find unclear exactly?

Comment: I had the same issue! This is being caused because Particles is initialised before owl. If you change the order of execution, and initialise the owl first and then the particles, this issue will not happen. But catching the slide event of bootstrap and initialising particle js seems not a good method, because it will initialize particle js on every slide. Also, you need to give more details in your answer. 

Writing an answer is not just for the one who asked the question, but also for others who come here to read it. But initialising the particles inside the carousel is not right practice.

Comment: @simonmysun To be clear, the part where you suggest to initialise partical.js inside the slide event is not clear. It is a statement, but not explanatory. I will retract the vote if you add more explanation and use case in your answer.

Comment: @Sibidharan Sorry for replying late. I did not wrote too much detail because I thought it was an upstream issue. ButI will explain it later. Have you solved your problem?

Comment: @simonmysun, yes, changing the order in which the Owl and Particles is initialized will solve the issue. It is live in http://rmr.solutions