# generating a random position inside a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

Im looking for a way on generating a random position on my html div. I've created a javascript function which looks like this:

```
function randomInRange(min, max) {
    return(Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min) + 1) + min));    
}
```

I wanted to generate a random position in the div's css by changing (position:relative; left:0px; top:0px) the left and top attribute to the random generated number. I can't seem to find a max & min value for the function since the div uses percentages for the widths.

css of the div:

```
#stage {
    float: left;
    background-color: pink;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70%;
}
```

the function executes when i click a certain button

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.onclick = function () {
    shape.style.left = randominrange(0, stage.style.width);
    shape.style.top = randominrange(0, stage.style.height);   
}
//the shape is a circle div that shows where the generated point is
```

i just started javascript a few days ago and cant seem to find a way to do it

Comment: So the problem is that you can't find the width of the div?

Answer (score 0):

The minimums would be 0 and the maximums would be the appropriate width and height properties of the element. [See here for an understanding of the different width properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845027/what-is-difference-between-width-innerwidth-and-outerwidth-height-innerheight).

I would assume you want `element.outerWidth(true)` and `element.outerHeight(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var stage = document.getElementById('stage');
var stageWidth = stage.offsetWidth;
var stageHeight = stage.offsetHeight
```

Now you can use stageWidth & stageHeight for your function calls

Answer (score 0):

Use `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` instead of `width` and `height`

```
button.onclick = function () {
    shape.style.left = randominrange(0, stage.style.clientWidth);
    shape.style.top = randominrange(0, stage.style.clientHeight);   
}
```

here is a difference between [clientHeight vs offsetHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106538/difference-between-offsetheight-and-clientheight)

Comment: Thanks! It worked but the random position often gets farther outside the div and overflows