# Query dom element's properties Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-directives

I am trying to create a directive that will make my layouts full height. To do so, i am using the code below:

```
import { HostListener, Directive, ElementRef, Input, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({ selector: '[fill-height]' })

export class FillHeightDirective implements AfterViewInit {


    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.calculateAndSetElementHeight();
    }

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    onResize(event) {
        this.calculateAndSetElementHeight();
    }

    private calculateAndSetElementHeight() {
        this.el.nativeElement.style.overflow = 'auto';
        const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
        const elementOffsetTop = this.getElementOffsetTop();
        const elementMarginBottom = this.el.nativeElement.style.marginBottom;
        const footerElementMargin = this.getfooterElementMargin();

        this.el.nativeElement.style.height = windowHeight - footerElementMargin - elementOffsetTop + 'px';
        console.log([windowHeight, elementOffsetTop, elementMarginBottom, footerElementMargin, this.el.nativeElement.style.height]);
    }

    private getElementOffsetTop() {
        return this.el.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    }

    private getfooterElementMargin() {
        const footerElement = document.getElementById('footer');
        const footerStyle = window.getComputedStyle(footerElement);
        return parseInt(footerStyle.height, 10);
    }
}
```

This works fine but i want a way not to hard code the footer id. This directive will be used on elements that aren't related to the footer in any way so i can't use @ViewChild or @Input. I thought i would create another directive to get this information (element height)  and it looks like this:

```
@Directive({ selector: '[footer]' })

export class NbFooterDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.getElementHeight();
    }

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    onResize(event) {
        this.getElementHeight();
    }

    private getElementHeight() {
        return this.el.nativeElement.style.height;
    }
}
```

Now i want a way to pass this height data from this directive to the first directive that does the computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `this.el.nativeElement.style` is the style attribute and not the computed style. If you want to get computed styles use 'window.getComputedStyle' bit for the case of height if the height will be for example `auto` it'll give just a string `'auto'`. So if you want real computed height use `this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight` or `this.el.nativeElement.clientHeight`. Take a look at this answer for more: [offsetHeight vs clienHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4106585/3793239).

I have created an example for my solution of your problem. So please follow the [plunker link](https://embed.plnkr.co/92c136OgjkhOmhFIPhij/) and look at the code.

The basic concept is that you should have an output on the first component and listen to that from the second one.

Comment: Thanks, just what i was looking for. This is working for me though I later resorted to using observables to pass information from one directive to the other. Thanks again.