# Get CSS property of <ul> <li> child node with vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I get CSS properties of an child element of a node?
I want to get the height of the `<li>` element of a `<ul>`

**style.scss**

```
ul.menu {
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
   li {
      height: 28px;
    }
}
```

**javascript**

```
let elementList = this.dropdownMenu.nativeElement.children;
console.log(elementList.length);
console.log(/*height of li*/);
```

**I prefer solutions with vanilla JavaScript without using jQuery!**

Comment: you can get its height by using jquery or javascript in jquery we use
$('ul li'').outerHeight() something like this\

Comment: I prefer solutions without the usage of jQuery!

Comment: Sure let me make one fiddle

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4106538/difference-between-offsetheight-and-clientheight) out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your case, where the html looks like:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

And css:

```
ul.menu {
   width: 100%;
   float: left;
}

ul.menu li {
  height: 28px;
}
```

Your working javascript should be:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("menu")[0];

for (var i = 0; i < list.children.length; ++i) {
    var clientHeight = list.children[i].clientHeight,
        offsetHeight = list.children[i].offsetHeight;
    console.log(clientHeight); // with padding
    console.log(offsetHeight); // with borders
}
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615552/get-div-height-with-plain-javascript).

Comment: This works great! Is there also a way how to get the properties of the border of the `<ul>`-list element?

Comment: have you tried using `getPropertyValue` like element.getPropertyValue('border-width') ?